# How can I remove packages untracked by pacman I installed from source?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

Hey so the question pretty much says it all, I've installed the irc client quassel and I want to get rid of it now but I don't know how to do so with pacman because I installed it from the source code, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible. If you installed it from source, you better hope its makefile has an `uninstall` target. This is why it is never recommended to install things from source without just making a `PKGBUILD` of your own.

Comment: What is the package? The only sure way is to do it again - without the `make install` part - or with it and a different prefix - and try to follow all of the leads. It isn't *so* hard - an empty directory prefix might be helpful - and then backtrack to your regular folders. Also there is `pacman -Qo` for verifying the files you think came from the package don't belong to any tracked installs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a script on the Arch Wiki [pacman tips page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_tips#Identify_files_not_owned_by_any_package) for finding files not owned by any package. That will assist you tracking down what was installed with quassel.

In future, you should only ever use pacman to install packages, so they remain tracked and you don't end up cluttering your system with unmanaged files. Using [ABS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Abs), [the AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR) or taking a little time to write your own PKGBUILD is the correct way to approach this.

Comment: So i need to find all the files it installed and manually remove them?

Comment: @user3610218 Ultimately, yes...

Answer (score 0):

You could force install qassel from the repos/aur, which *should* overwrite the source installed files and then remove the package, assuming stuff got installed to /usr and not /usr/local.
For future reference, learn to write PKGBUILD buildscripts and use them to do from source installs, this results in a pacman package that you can install and remove more or less like repo packages.